# R - incomplete final line and embedded nulls

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to learn how to use R and I'd like to run simple/multiple/logistic regressions but I am stuck right at the beginning. I have succesfully loaded an spss database in R using this code:

```
> library(foreign)
> data<-read.spss("new long an.sav", use.value.labels=TRUE, to.data.frame=TRUE)
re-encoding from UTF-8
> data
```

Then, I was trying to specify the data file I want to undertake my regressions on by doing as following:

```
> newlongan<-read.delim("new long an.sav", header = TRUE)
```

However, the following error messages comes up and I am not sure how to solve them:

```
> Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'new long an.sav'
```

I have got car, boot and QuantPsyc installed. Do you have any idea? Thanks

Silvia

Comment: What do you mean by `specify`? Why do you want to use `read.delim` if `read.spss` already worked?

Comment: Because I was using different scripts, so I thought that somehow I needed to reload my data file by using read.delim. I thought I may not need it so I have tried to use the following code to run my simple regression:

>regModel<- lm(IQ ~ P_Irritability, data = new long an, na.action = na.exclude)

But it doesn't work. I think the problem is in the line "data = ..." I have tried to specify my dataFrame in different ways (data, new long an, "new long an.spss") but still no results. There are always unexpected symbols and similar issues.

Comment: You said in your question: `I have succesfully loaded an spss database in R using this code [...] data<-read.spss("new long an.sav", use.value.labels=TRUE, to.data.frame=TRUE)`. There's your data. Right there. If you want to, type `new_long_an <- read.spss("new long an.sav", use.value.labels=TRUE, to.data.frame=TRUE)` instead to give the object another name.

Comment: Thanks now it is more clear. I have changed the name of my object and tried to re-run a regression but still it doesn't work. Here's what I am using: 

>regModel<- lm(IQ ~ P_Irritability, data = new_long_an, na.action = na.exclude)